# facebook opengraph api return limitations?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm just experimenting with opengraph a bit and I was trying to retrieve all the posts a user has ever made. And I noticed that when do
user_id/statuses?limit=200

it only returns 99 statusses, is this because i'm doing it trough the graph api explorer on developers.facebook.com? is there a way to get all the users posts with the extra information, like in graph(comments/likes...)?

the next/previous links didn't help they both returned an empty json string

Comment: the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) "should" return identical data as querying the actual API.

Answer (score 1):

there are some limitations enforced here - if a user has (hypothetically) seven million posts, Facebook's servers will be bogged down with your request.  All requests have a limitation on them - even if not specifically set.  Pay attention to the parameters in the `next` and `prev` pagination links.  They contain values such as :

- `limit` - how many items will be returned in each request
- `offset` - an offset to start from, an offset of 15 will start returning posts from the 15th and onward.
- `since` - epoch timestamp defining the begining of a timeframe
- `untill`- epoch timestamp defining the end of a timeframe

Hope this info helps...

Comment: ok but then why doesn't this work? am I doing something wrong? /statuses?format=json&limit=99&until=1296298003 this is supposed to be january 29 2010 but instead it returns empty and change it to "since=1296298003" return the latest 99... so i've only gotten as far as viewing the last 99 posts so far :s

Comment: Note that there is an issue of privacy here.  It depends on the actual posts privacy settings also...

Comment: what do you mean? apps can't access posts older than a month or so? couldn't that permission be requested?

Comment: No no... I meant that posts could have been marked with limited visibility - according to privacy settings.  "Public" has a different meaning when browsing Facebook pages and users as a REAL user and using the graph api...

Comment: I just tried changing a few privacy options.... still nothing... (i'm testing al lthis on my own account btw) even using fql I can't access any "old" posts :s

Answer (score 1):

There is also a limit in the amount of information that Facebook allows to be gotten via the Graph API.  The data stores for the public Graph API are not the same as the data stores Facebook uses for the normal GUI.  If your app desperately needs full information, it is possible that becoming a Facebook partner might get you better results.